# WCF basicHttpBinding and HTTP proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, http-proxy

I'm trying to get my generated WCF ServiceClient to send its requests to the WCF service through a **HTTP** (not HTTP**S**) proxy with username/password authentication, however I just can't get it work. My WCF service uses basicHttpBinding so I tried to configure my ServiceClient instance like so:

```
var svc = new ServiceClient();
var b = svc.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;

b.ProxyAddress = new Uri(proxyAddress);
b.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;
b.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
b.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
b.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;

svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = proxyUsername;
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = proxyPassword;
```

This however results in a System.ArgumentException saying:

> The provided URI scheme http is invalid. expected https

When I set the `b.Security.Mode` to `BasicHttpSecurityMode.None` though, it seems the HTTP proxy settings are ignored by WCF altogether!

The second solution I tried was to set the DefaultWebProxy property of WebRequest and set the UseDefaultWebProxy property to true such as so:

```
var webProxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress, true);
webProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyUsername, proxyPassword);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;

var svc = new ServiceClient();

var b = svc.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;
b.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
```

However this also doesn't work and ServiceClient doesn't send it's requests through the HTTP proxy.

I'm out of ideas here so please let me know what I am doing wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the security mode to BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly. This allows for passing plain-text authentication details over HTTP.

Comment: Thank you, but this results in a InvalidOperationException saying: 'You cannot specify an explicit Proxy Address as well as UseDefaultWebProxy=true in your HTTP transport binding element'. However nowhere in my code do I have set UseDefaultWebProxy to true and there's absolutely nothing about a DefaultWebProxy in the app.config service configuration either??

Comment: Turns out I had to explicitly set UseDefaultWebProxy = false. I thought it'd be false by default. Well it's working now, so thank you very much!